# Use a different starting view on second launch of app

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.1

I have two apps; the first app will launch the second app and then when clicking the "Back" button, it will launch the first app again for a second time.

Assuming I have three views (view1, view2, view3), on my first launch of the apps, it will start on view1 by default, but I need it to start on view2 on my second launch of the apps. How can I do that? Can anyone at least give me some clues?

I'm using a push view for swiping from view1, view2 and view3.

This app is used on an iPhone/iPod on iOS 3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`NSUserDefault`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/boolForKey%3a) .

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstTime"]) 
{   
    [self displayFirstView];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"firstTime"];
}
else
{
    [self displaySecondView];
}
```

Comment: Thanks,
instead of using `[self displayFirstView]` i replaced it with `[self pushView:viewController]` 
Due to the way i link the next view, i usually do it in the interface builder linking the view and the class. But in appDelegate, the declared class file did not show up on the interface builder, any idea to link that class(for that 2nd view) on appDelegate ?

Comment: opps, i found the answer, its on the mainWindow. anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to keep track of whether the app has been launched before. I suggest you do this in `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` of your app delegate.